# after data loaded via ajax container has incorrect height overalpping footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML markup mainly contains container with two columns (content and sidebar) and footer. Content contains `ul.horizontal-list` with `li` elements. `Li` elements are populated via ajax on Load More button press. I am using bootstrap, testing on Chrome, Win7. 
I have two related problems/questions.

First: I am loadng data using 'Load More' button via ajax call. As a result container overlaps footer, as for some reason container height doesnot change correctly. I am not able to fix it.

Here is result after data were loaded (grey data are over footer, also height of  left side sidebar have not changed enough).

[image: Loading data via ajax doesn't change height of container and sidebar]

Second: There is script running on page load. It was not written by me and I didn't know about it before someone commented about it below. This script changes content and sidebars height on load, it sets fixed height for both columns. Thus probably this is the reason why ajax load doesn't change height correctly. **I don't really think that setting the same height of two columns in bootstrap should be done via javascript.** Is there any other non-javascript sollution, why javascript sollution was used here?

Real exmample can be seen in this page: http://moneyti.co/ (if you scroll down and press Load more button).

Javascript code that seems to set fixed height for columns with class `.equalcol`.

```
/**
 * Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows
 * https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows
 */
(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery.fn.equalHeight = function() {
        var heights = [];
        jQuery.each(this, function(i, element) {
            jQueryelement = jQuery(element);
            var element_height;
            var includePadding = (jQueryelement.css('box-sizing') == 'border-box') || (jQueryelement.css('-moz-box-sizing') == 'border-box');
            if (includePadding) {
                element_height = jQueryelement.innerHeight();
            } else {
                element_height = jQueryelement.height();
            }
            heights.push(element_height);
        });
        this.height(Math.max.apply(window, heights));
        return this;
    };
    jQuery.fn.equalHeightGrid = function(columns) {
        var jQuerytiles = this;
        jQuerytiles.css('height', 'auto');
        for (var i = 0; i < jQuerytiles.length; i++) {
            if (i % columns === 0) {
                var row = jQuery(jQuerytiles[i]);
                for (var n = 1; n < columns; n++) {
                    row = row.add(jQuerytiles[i + n]);
                }
                row.equalHeight();
            }
        }
        return this;
    };
    jQuery.fn.detectGridColumns = function() {
        var offset = 0,
            cols = 0;
        this.each(function(i, elem) {
            var elem_offset = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
            if (offset === 0 || elem_offset == offset) {
                cols++;
                offset = elem_offset;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return cols;
    };
    jQuery.fn.responsiveEqualHeightGrid = function() {
        var _this = this;

        function syncHeights() {
            var cols = _this.detectGridColumns();
            _this.equalHeightGrid(cols);
        }
        jQuery(window).bind('resize load', syncHeights);
        syncHeights();
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery('.equalcol').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
});
```

**Main HTML markup:**

```
 <div class="contents">
        <!-- Content Column Start -->
        <div class="custom-container front-container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="front-page col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 equalcol conentsection">
                    <div id="pl-343">                        
                        <div class="panel-grid" id="pg-343-5">
                            <div class="panel-grid-cell" id="pgc-343-5-0">
                                <ul class="horizontal-list">
                                    <li class="post-2978 vmgallery type-vmgallery status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry gallery_categories-dazadi-un-episki">
                                        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 horizontal-list-media">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 info">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </li>
                                     ...
                                </ul>
                                <div class="loader" style="display: none;">
                                </div><button id="load_more_mix_homepage">Load more</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Dark Sidebar Start -->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 equalcol blacksidebar">
                    ...
                   <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Dark Sidebar End -->
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Contents End -->
    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <footer class="style1">
        <div class="custom-container">

            <div class="row footerwidgets">               
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9 .col-xs-9">                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 .col-xs-3">                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: On which browser? Seems to work as expected on chrome

Comment: Which OS? Like said, it works for me on win7 as expected once data loaded. But i'd be surprised this issue being relative to any OS. That's said, when i click, and before data added, i can see the overlapping. Is that your issue?

Comment: Chrome, Win7 give me above screenshot.

Comment: Please, try to press more than once. It seems that it depands on data returned and screen width/height, sometimes you can see and sometimes not.

Comment: Ya, you are correct. I'm able to replicate it if clicking it more times. But once i do some resize, e.g opening console, it gone away. I'm sorry but not sure what happen here. Cazn you provide in question itself the way new datas are added and any relevant custom CSS you are using (if any)?

Comment: Please add the script that set the height of `.front-page col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 equalcol conentsection`. http://i.stack.imgur.com/pn1SY.png

Comment: @MoshFeu Please, see above, I have attached javascript. It really changes height of columns and set fixed height. This is necessary to have two equal size columns. This is not my code, I was not familiar with this, unfourtunately still cannot fix this load more problem.

Comment: Well, maybe that's the problem. You need to run this code after each DOM changes so it will calculate the height again..

Answer (score 0):

Usually the content won't reach it's proper size unless all the images are loaded. If you notice, when the images are cached, the bug won't be reproduced. There are many solutions to this problem.

- You could set a `timeout` for about a second and refresh the height.
- You could add a `load listener` on every image and refresh the height once they are all loaded.
- You could set the image width and height attributes server side so the `img` tag will occupy the proper amount of space even if the image is not loaded.
- Set a fixed height on the `img` or its parent.

In my opinion, the first approach is the easiest and the safer.